# File reading from one to another file and printing in Python

Tags: python

The following code is working as expected. As I have taken `InputStr.txt` in that I have filled some string of statements and generating the Output.txt by adding those InputStr.txt statements whether PASS or FAIL.

Python Code:

```
str = "FAIL";
flag = False;
resultList = [];

#Here InputStr.txt is the file where all your output format strings are stored.
Stringlines = [line.strip() for line in open('InputStr.txt')]

out_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
for i in range (1,3):
    fileName1 = "./largeFile%d.txt"%i
    print fileName1;
    fileName2 = "./largeFile_%d.txt"%i
    with open(fileName1, 'r') as inF1:
        for line in inF1:
            if 'VERSION' in line:
                print "VERSION FOUND";
                flag = True;
    if flag:
        with open(fileName2, 'r') as inF2:
            for line in inF2:
                if 'ID' in line:
                    print "ID FOUND";
                    str = "PASS";

    resultList.append(str);
    out_file.write("\n %s - %s" %(Stringlines[i-1],resultList[i-1]))

out_file.close()
```

Output I got:

```
Output in Output.txt is:*

TEST CASE-1 PASS
TEST CASE-2 PASS
TEST CASE-3 PASS
```

I am trying to print the TC1 should PASS when 4TCs should PASS as these 4TCs i took from another InputStr2.txt.

Example:

InputStr.txt contains following statements:

```
Req 1. How How are you
Req 2. I am Fine and Thanks.
Req 3. How are you doing
```

InputStr2.txt contains:

```
TC1:  ABCDEFGHIJ
TC2:  KLMNOPQRST
TC3:  UVWXYZABCD
TC4:  EFGHIJKLMN
```

So expected output is:

```
Req 1. How How are you - PASS
Req 2. I am Fine and Thanks. - PASS
Req 3. How are you doing - PASS
```

First All the Test cases of TC1 to TC4 should PASS(In InputStr2.txt), then only my Req 1 will PASS. Means, In Output.txt i am printing all the requirements are PASS or FAIL.

Logic/suggestions please?